# Standard Deviation with advanced use of FILTER

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 persons where each have a score in 5 tests (score may also be blank)
Each test can have 1-3 Types (A,B and C).
I can SUM the total of the scores per type but I can't calculate the Standard Deviation per type.
What I thought I could do is use the FILTER function to bring the values for scores of the type. To do this, I tried an array of 3 FILTERs, each checks if the respective row (6-8) has Type A in it:
={FILTER(F2:J4,F6:J6="A"),FILTER(F2:J4,F7:J7="A"),FILTER(F2:J4,F8:J8="A")}

This works if each of the 3 rows has at least one "A" , but if any of the rows (6-8) doesn't have "A" I get a #REF error.
I tried wrapping each of the FILTER functions in a IFERROR but it doesn't work as well IFNA(FILTER(F2:J4,F8:J8="A")

Here's the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yk57wY6vnKNNYoN18_EvEcQ3atqQDr41M5cguDR1_d0/edit#gid=0

In C13 is my formula that fails since there's no "A" in row 8. If I add "A" in H8 it will work.
In C15 is the formula with IFNA, that also doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using `hstack` instead of `curved braces` within your existing formula since it can handle the missing array(s) w/out error*

```js
=stdev(ifna(hstack(FILTER(F2:J4,F6:J6="A"),FILTER(F2:J4,F7:J7="A"),FILTER(F2:J4,F8:J8="A"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks! Never heard of HSTACK till today, thanks again